# Is it possible to have two bottom navigation bars linked to a NavGraph?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm developing an application in which an user can identify himself with two different roles (administrator and user)

The user can access to six fragments according to their role (three for each role type), right now I have a bottom navigation bar linked to the NavGraph for the user type role.

Is it possible to have another bottom navigation bar linked to the NavGraph and show or hide them depending the role type?

I decided to use two bottom navigation bars, because it only supports five menu items, and in this case there are six.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can add all nav-graphs you need up front, add all menu items dynamically in code and point to the correct nav-graph

Comment: @ChristianoBolla thanks for your answer, I finally made two different XML menus for both types of users and inflated them depending on the role of user.